# HashMap. Use of custom type as Value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have class Computer and want to use Computer as type for value, not String. But I'm getting an error:

> Error:(22, 36) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to com.example.lesson18.Computer

```
public class Main {
private static Map<Integer, Computer> catalogComputersMap;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    catalogComputersMap = new HashMap<Integer, Computer>();
    ComputerStore cs = new ComputerStore();
    catalogComputersMap.put(1, "2 x 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, 512 GB, GeForce 210, 350 Watt");
    catalogComputersMap.put(2, "2 x 3.2 GHZ, 8 GB, 1 TB, Radeon R7 370, 550 Watt");
```

I have generated equals() and hashCode() in Computer class (is this what I need?) but result stays the same. Working code must be with `<Integer, Computer>` and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you all. Final solution is `catalogComputersMap.put(1, new Computer("2 x 1.6 GHz", "4 GB", "512 GB", "GeForce 210", "350 Watt"));`

In Computer class my object 
`public Computer(String processor, String ram, String hdd, String videoCard, String powerSupply) {
 this.processor = processor;
 this.ram = ram;
 this.hdd = hdd;
 this.videoCard = videoCard;
 this.powerSupply = powerSupply;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting an String inside the map as value.

You have to create an computer object with the values you want the object to have. I don't know what your computer object looks like but if it has an constructor that takes an string the code would look like this

```
Computer computer = new Computer("2 x 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, 512 GB, GeForce 210, 350 Watt");
catalogComputersMap.put(1, computer);
```

Comment: Computer object is 
`    public Computer(String processor, String ram, String hdd, String videoCard, String powerSupply) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.ram = ram;
        this.hdd = hdd;
        this.videoCard = videoCard;
        this.powerSupply = powerSupply;
    } `
I just simplified all to one String to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

But in this line:

```
catalogComputersMap.put(1, "2 x 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, 512 GB, GeForce 210, 350 Watt");
```

You are passing a String as second argument instead a Computer Object. You should pass a Computer to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call method with (int, String) arguments where the method expects (int, Computer) arguments. If your Computer class have constructor that have String parameter you can pass to the put method.

```
catalogComputersMap = new HashMap<Integer, Computer>();
ComputerStore cs = new ComputerStore();
catalogComputersMap.put(1, new Computer("2 x 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, 512 GB, GeForce 210, 350 Watt"));
catalogComputersMap.put(2, new Computer("2 x 3.2 GHZ, 8 GB, 1 TB, Radeon R7 370, 550 Watt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass String "2 x 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, 512 GB, GeForce 210, 350 Watt" as a value instead of Computer. Your Computer class must be like this:

```
public class Computer {

private String info;

public void setInfo(String info){
this.info = info;
}

public String getInfo (){
return this.info;
}

public Computer (String info){
this.info = info;
}
}
```

And then:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Map<Integer, Computer> catalogComputersMap = new HashMap<Integer, Computer>();

        catalogComputersMap.put(1, new Computer("2 x 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, 512 GB, GeForce 210, 350 Watt"));
        catalogComputersMap.put(2, new Computer("2 x 3.2 GHZ, 8 GB, 1 TB, Radeon R7 370, 550 Watt"));
}
```